# CouchDB won't delete database with $ in name

Tags: couchdb

I am trying to delete a CouchDB database with the name:

```
supertest$my(2e)name(40)myhost(2e)co(2e)uk
```

The database name is created automatically by the Superlogin node.js package so I do not have control over the use of a $ in the name (it is the $ that is causing the problem).

If I try to delete this database with the Fauxton admin interface clicking on the delete button does nothing. I have also tried to delete via the API as follows:

```
curl -vX DELETE http://127.0.0.1:5984/supertest$my(2e)name(40)myhost(2e)co(2e)uk
```

This API call is rejected with the error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: Fauxton interface is having few problems with Database URI. As for the direct API call, you need to encode the field I guess.

Comment: Do you have remote access to the server itself? In a worst-case scenario, you can manually delete the database file in `/var/lib/couchdb`.

Comment: You may also try wrapping the URL in single quotes for your `curl` command, seems like it's trying to do some interpolation because of the `$`.

Comment: I tried wrapping in quotes and it now complains that the database doesn't existing so I am guessing it is the $ still causing a problem.

Comment: I am running CouchDB on a Mac but can't find var/lib/couchdb so can't try that suggestion either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ran into the problem myself and ended up using the Superlogin API to remove the user and all their databases using

```
superlogin.removeUser(user_id, destroyDBs)
```

pass `true` as the second argument to remove their private DB.

https://github.com/colinskow/superlogin#superloginremoveuseruser_id-destroydbs

Comment: Thanks Mark. Will this remove both the local PouchDB and the remote synced CouchDB or does it just affect the CouchDB?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm using PouchDB in Node almost as an ORM for a locally installed Couch instance. I guess it will remove from the local pouchDB if that's what you've instantiated Superlogin against. You might need to call a manual sync on your DB to reflect those changes on the remote CouchDB - but again I'm not certain of that.

Comment: Is there a way to do removeUser via HTTP GET/PUT?

Comment: Sadly not, but there's nothing to stop you wrapping the removeUser API method in your own endpoint and using that.

Comment: Thanks Mark I will try that.

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me:

```
curl -gvX DELETE 'http://user:password@mydomain.com:5984/client$someuser(40)gmail(2e)com'
```

The single quotes make bash look at it as a string (solves your issue).

The curl -g, --globoff Disable URL sequences and ranges using {} and [] was needed because I have those characters in my passwords from time to time.